# MovieClip Last Frame event Handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling

If my Document.as adds a movieclip to the stage how can I remove that movieClip when it reaches its last frame?

Document.as

```
private var MainVideo:MovieClip = new my_video();
addChild(MainVideo);

    MainVideo.addEventListener("movieclip_stopped", _stopHandler);

    function _stopHandler(e:Event):void
            {
                trace('mc was stopped');
            }
```

And on the last frame of my MovieClip I put:

```
stop();

MainVideo.dispatchEvent(new Event("movieclip_stopped"));
```

But of course I am getting `ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MainVideo is not defined.`  since the movieclip doesnt understand who or what created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that:

```
this.dispatchEvent(...);
```

From inside the movie clip you refer to the movie clip using `this`. From outside, you use a reference to the object, like `MainVideo`.